# The useCallback and useEffect functions are incompatible and produce an error

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

In my code I'm trying to combine font loading and logged in user detection, but using useCallback and useEffect triggers an over-rendering error.

```
// App.js

// All imports are correct

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  // Loading fonts
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    "SF-Pro-Display-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf")
  });
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!fontError && fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontError, fontsLoaded]);
  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  // User detection
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authUser) => {
      setUser(authUser);
    });

    return unsubscribe; // Zwraca funkcję do odsubskrybowania zdarzenia
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user !== null ? <AppNavigation /> : <InitialNavigation />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Errors I receive when running the application:

```
ERROR  Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://react.dev/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useEffect                  useEffect
4. useCallback                useCallback
5. undefined                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    in App (at withDevTools.js:18)
    in withDevTools(App) (at renderApplication.js:57)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67)
 ERROR  Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

This error is located at:
    in App (at withDevTools.js:18)
    in withDevTools(App) (at renderApplication.js:57)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes
```

I would be grateful if someone could solve my error without changing the purpose of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
        return null;
    }
```

this should be called only after all hooks, because each hook should be called every render, not conditionally. That is basic principle of hooks.

So, just move this `if` code right before `return`